# How to implement freezing of first two or three columns in power bi report

Tags: powerbi

How to implement freezing of first two or three columns in table visual in power bi report

Answer (score 1):

Please see the attached screenshot. I have already **drilled** down to the lowest level. I can see Product ID and Product Name. These 2 columns are **frozen**.

[image]

Comment: Actually, it is a kind of requirement in which first 3 columns are frozen and rest 12 columns should be scrollable. It is same like freeze pane option in excel but not able to implement this in power bi. Can anybody please guide on this? Thanks for this solution by the way.

Comment: As freezing of columns in table functionality is not available in power bi directly, I created two table visuals and sorted them on the same column which led me to give the same flexibility as that of freeze pane functionality in excel.

Thanks for the guidance.